Looking for the definition of the trivial representation of a $(A,B) \ C^*$ - correspondance.
As it is said here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_representation ,

A trivial representation is a representation $(V, \phi)$ of a group $G$ on which all elements of $G$ act as the identity mapping of $ V$.
A trivial representation of an associative or Lie algebra is a (Lie) algebra representation for which all elements of the algebra act as the zero linear map (endomorphism) which sends every element of $V$ to the zero vector.

My question is,
Let $A$ and $B$ be any two $C^*$-algebras.
What is the definition of the trivial representation of a $(A,B)$ $C^*$ - correspondance ?
For more informations about the definition of the notion of a representation of a $C^*$-correspondance, see here, https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.14605 , page, $11$.
Thanks in advance for your help.

The word "trivial" doesn't appear to be used anywhere in the linked paper. With no further context my only guess is that it's the representation where both Hilbert spaces are zero.

Also I really have to quibble with the idea that an associative algebra has a trivial representation. That's only true if we don't require units or don't require homomorphisms to preserve the unit.

I concur with Qiaochu that most likely “trivial” representation refers to the zero map. There’s really no other “natural” “trivial” maps from a Hilbert bimodule to $L(H_1,H_2)$. I don’t necessarily agree with saying “trivial representation” is a weird idea, seeing that plenty of people work with non-unital $C^\ast$-algebras, but I have to agree in this case, it’s a bit awkward. The author even seemed to assume a representation should not be zero at one point (otherwise there’s no point citing a reference to say such representations exist - which the author did immediately after defining them).
